# Not able to get value for selected radio button in list view

Tags: android, listview, radio-button

I am  implementing single choice radio button in list view and I am able to achieve it. Now, I am getting problem that is I want to send value of selected radio button to the fragment but I am getting null pointer exception regarding this.

Here is my code:

```
RadioButton selected=null;

viewHolder.radioChoose_address.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if(selected != null)
        {
            selected.setChecked(false);
        }

        viewHolder.radioChoose_address.setChecked(true);
        selected = viewHolder.radioChoose_address;
    }
});

if(viewHolder.radioChoose_address.isChecked())
{
    deliveryOrderConfirm.checkedAddressValue = addressModel.getAddressId();
}
```

In the code for the fragment I only do declare a variable:

```
public String checkedAddressValue;
```

Comment: put your if block inside the setOnClickListener.

Comment: Try to do this code with `oncheckedchanged`.

Comment: 1) RadioButton selected=null; you haven't instantiated with any other value. It is null.
2) you are checking if(selected != null), but if it is null surely null pointer exception will occur. Because you are using select blow the if(selected != null) content.